# copy noise curve

Tags: modifiers, graph-editor, data-blocks

I need to change the Noise Modifier data in a noise loop. I want to divide by 2 the frame numbers because the cycle is too much long.
To change this in just 1 object is not a problem, but my scene (6x at 2000 samples and 750 frames) is full of objects...
How to copy the noise curve of the keyframe in the Graph Editor from a n object to another one?

Thanx!
Andrea